# finer-grained role/type access (specifically auditd_log_t)

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, selinux, rhel-7

Suppose I want to use SELinux to lock down audit logs even more tightly than ordinary logs.  Ordinary logs typically have type `var_log_t`, but audit logs have type `auditd_log_t`.  So there's at least a basis for discriminating their access.

What (I think) I want to do is have a couple of different administrator role types, both of which can access objects of type `var_log_t`, but only the more privileged of which can access objects of type `auditd_log_t`.  But so far I haven't found how to view (let alone adjust) the core rules that say "May *subject* do *action* to *object*?"

As it stands now, if I have an "ordinary" administrator of user class `staff_u`, with a sudo upgrade path to `sysadm_r` as described at [3.9. Confining an administrator by using sudo and the sysadm_r role](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/using_selinux/managing-confined-and-unconfined-users_using-selinux#confining-an-administrator-using-sudo-and-the-sysadm_r-role_managing-confined-and-unconfined-users), that user can access both the "ordinary" logs and the audit logs (that is, objects of both types `var_log_t` and `auditd_log_t`).  I want to deny this "ordinary" admin access to the audit logs, and restrict that access to some higher-level admin.

Or perhaps I'm on the wrong track?

I realize that `sysadm_r` is already the highest-level, most-privileged administrator, so perhaps I merely have to find an existing but lesser admin role and only allow my `staff_u` user to upgrade to that.
And if I knew how to list the roles which are allowed to access objects of various types, I'm thinking that would be a good way to find clues about what that lesser admin role might be.